# Angular - Passing Json Object to Child displaying [Object Object]

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm making a basic API call. My Input component file has the code as below

Input.html

```
<form (submit)="getTransactions()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="address" name="address" placeholder="Bitoin Address">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {{address}}
  </div>
</form>

<app-display [address]="transactions"></app-display>
```

input.ts

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

  address = "3MvuMn4CESuvA89bfA1cT8mgC4JtKaReku";
  transactions = [];

  constructor(private blockchain: BlockchainService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.address)
  }

  getTransactions(){
    this.blockchain.getTransactions().subscribe((data) => {
      // console.log(data.json())
      this.transactions = data.json();
      console.log(this.transactions)
    });
  }

}
```

When I console.log to check to make sure the json object is displaying correctly in my Input component it works.

When I console.log in my Display component, I see
"[object Object]". No error is being printed.

Thanks guys, this will be a learning point for me.

display.htlm

```
<button (click)="hello()"></button>
```

display.ts

```
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() address = [];

  constructor(private blockchain: BlockchainService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  hello(){
    console.log(`data ${this.address}`);
  }

}
```

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BlockchainService {

  baseurl: string = "http://localhost:4200/assets/info.json"

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getTransactions(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code may be help you

```
   this.blockchain.getTransactions().subscribe(
                        (data => {
                            if (data['status'] == 200) {
                                this.transactions = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
}
    }),
                        error => this.toastr.error('Something went wrong !!', 'Oops!',{showCloseButton: true})
                    );
```

or edit this in your service

```
return this._http.get("your path").map(data => data.json())

this.blockchain.getTransactions().subscribe(
                            (data => {
                                if (data) {
                                    this.transactions = data;
    }
        }),
                            error => this.toastr.error('Something went wrong !!', 'Oops!',{showCloseButton: true})
                        );
```

Comment: can you share your service?

Comment: Shared. also the code you provided is giving me syntax error.

Comment: do you have toaster? in your app and i edited my code check and tell

Comment: see my given code and if you need any help mention in comments

Answer (score 0):

you need parse the json object (`address`) in your `DisplayComponent` component.

```
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() address: any;

  constructor(private blockchain: BlockchainService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
this.address  = JSON.parse(this.address);
  }

  hello(){
    console.log(`data ${this.address}`);
  }

}
```

as you have applied `.json()` method in your Input component

Comment: I receive an error that says "[ts] Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'." when i try to add the statement to ngOnInit

Comment: you can change  `@Input() address = []` to `@Input() address :any`